# generacion de excel muy grande c#

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, asp.net, excel

Tengo un problema generando un excel muy grande con mas o menos 700 000 filas,  unas 90 columnas y cada ceda con cadenas de textos, ya lo he intentado de muchas formas y de ninguna funciona, una de ellas fue  llamando los datos desde un api, y creando el excel en el front-end (VueJs), pero al crear el excel el navegador se reventa [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues de esto entonces decidi hacerlo en el backend que esta hecho en c# y al hacer esto mi pc genera el excel pero maximo con 20 columnas por q con mas columnas se reventaba mi maquina un core i7 con 16 gb de ram,la cpu se va a tope, entonces ahora estoy tratanto de hacer el excel desde el mismo sql server un csv mediante sqlcmd y CMD pero ahora no se como llamar el codigo de cmd desde el api hecho en asp.net.

AYUDA :(

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar esto por el método q sea

DE ANTEMANO MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

En principio no veo limites en el excel

[Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Newer_versions)

Lo que recomendaria es que exportes usando una libreria basda en `open xml` como ser `ClosedXml`, esta la gregas con nuget

[ClosedXml nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/)

Entonces si los datos los tienes en un `DataTable` podrias volcarlos directamente, bueno si es una lista en base a una clase que definas tambien aplica

[Inserting Data](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Data)

analiza como usa el `InsertData()`

```
var dataTable = GetTable();

var rangeWithData = ws.Cell(7, 1).InsertData(dataTable.AsEnumerable());
```

Selecciona la celda donde quiere insertar y desd eesa posicion insertara el contenido del origen de datos

Comment: Hola Leandro muchas gracias por responder, estoy usando entity framework y en c# efectivamente estoy usando Closedxml, la consulta demora un poco pero me llegan los datos , luego lleno el excel asi  usando un forech
ws.Cell(2, 2).Value = "Initial Value";
ws.Cell(2, 3).Value = "Casting";

Comment: en lugar de asignar celda por celda porque no pruebas con el InsertData() pasandole la lista que obtienes desde EF

Comment: haciendo un seguimiento con puntos de interrupcion mi pc se cuelga es cuando hago workbook.SaveAs("CellValues.xlsx"); por que el foreach lo termina normalmente

Comment: No es que se cuelga, el proceso demora mas que la paciencia que le proporcionas, porque para probar lo dejas terminar para ver de cuento es esa demora. Ademas intenta proporcionar una ruta completa y no solo el nombre ya que no se que ruta este asignando.

Comment: Leandro, creo q si se cuelga, en el Administrador de tareas de Windows un proceso del iis se queda pegado y consumiendome el 95% de CPU y el pc se pone super lento, pero voy a probar cargándolo masiva mente con el InsertData() y esperando a ver si termina, espero que sea esa solucion, Leandro mi total admiración

Comment: leandro y una pregunta adicional, ¿se puede ejecutar un código  cmd desde un api en el servidor ? por ejemplo un sqlcmd -Q "SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Person" -o MyOutput.txt

Comment: Usando Process.Star() se puede https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/run-sql-server-scripts-using-c